# How can I delete (not disable) ActiveX add-ons in Internet Explorer (7 and 8 Beta 2)?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I'm developing a solution which uses an ActiveX control (a commercial one which we bought and that I did not develop). I need to develop the proper installation pages to simulate what happens when a user who has never visited the site and does not have the add-on installed comes to the page.

I've found the "Manage Add-Ons" bit in Internet Options and I'm not having any luck.

In IE7, I see an ability to enable or disable any control and a "Delete ActiveX" option, but it's disabled for this particular control.

In IE8 Beta 2, the "Manage Add-Ons" bit has been completely reworked and I no longer see an option to delete the control. Each control has a "Properties" dialog and I can "Remove" it, but the button doesn't appear to do anything (could be related to how "Delete ActiveX" doesn't work for this on in IE7).

It looks like maybe this control is installed in such a way that merely deleting it from IE won't work or isn't allowed, but it's not a control with its own entry on the Add/Remove Programs menu in XP, so I can't uninstall it that way either.

How can I delete/remove (not disable) this ActiveX control in IE so that I can simulate what happens when people come to the site and the ActiveX control hasn't been installed yet? I figure there must be a way to "purge" IE of it.

Comment: What I did in my case I searched my C drive for all occurrences of the dll that represented my activeX and removed all of them. I'm not sure if it would work in all cases though.

Comment: Removing dlls and .ax files is insufficient and not a good idea. There are registry entries, browser configuration for Add-ons, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could unregister the control with

```
regsvr32 /u badboy.ocx
```

at the command line. Though i would suggest testing these things in a vmware.

Comment: If regsvr32 does not work, try ...

     regasm badboy.dll /unregister

... as the ActiveX might be written in .NET with a COM wrapper.

Answer (score 9):

Close all browsers and tabs to ensure that the ActiveX control is not reside in memory.  Open a fresh IE9 browser. Select Tools->Manage Add-ons.  Change the drop down to "All add-ons" since the default only shows ones that are loaded.

Now select the add-on you wish to remove.  There will be a link displayed on the lower left that says "More information".  Click it.

This opens a further dialog that allows you to safely un-install the ActiveX control.

If you follow the direction of manually running the 'regsvr32' to remove the OCX it is not sufficient. ActiveX controls are wrapped up as signed CAB files and they extract to multiple DLLs and OCXs potentially.  You wish to use IE to safely and correctly unregister every COM DLL and OCX.

There you have it!  The problem is that in IE 9 it is somewhat hidden since you have to click the "More information" whereas IE8 you could do it from the same UI.

Comment: Thanks! Same process for IE11.

Answer (score 7):

Internet options-->General Tab-->browsing History section.... click settings and then click "View objects". A list of your active X add on's are displayed in the windows folder that they are stored in. You can manipulate these files as you would any others. Simply delete the ones you want to uninstall and restart IE.

Comment: I think this is obsolete info, at least for IE9, and one has to work with Manage Add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the "Remote" option in Configuration Menu for Plug-In works by me (Win7 64, ie8 with all updates), however:

1. You need administrator rights
2. The plug-in should be disabled before pressing the remove button
3. You need restart internet-explorer to see the changes.

Also the previous comment about browsing-history->view objects was also useful if plug-in was installed right now.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features, search for the Add-ons you would like to uninstall and click on particular one to uninstall.

Yes, I tried uninstalling from IE, Tools -> Manage Add-ons and then click "More Information" link at the bottom, however the "Remove" button was disabled. This didn't work.

Above mentioned solution for uninstalling from "Programs and Features" works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine.  Start fresh as often as you want, and stop doing these hacks that may or may not simulate a clean machine.

Seriously, use VMWare or VirtualPC.

Comment: I understand that one solution for this is a VM, but that's not what the question

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer.  Sometimes when the question is, "How do you do that?"  ... the best answer is "Don't.  Do this instead."

Answer (score -2):

Tools > Manage Add-ons, right click "Name" header and enable the "In Folder" section. go to the directory for the plugin you're interested in. Right click the plugin file, and click "remove".

Answer (score -2):

You can go to `IE Tools -> Internet options -> Advanced Tab`. Under Advanced, check for security and put a check on the 1st 2 options which says,"Allow active content from CDs to run on My Computer* and Allow active content to run in files on My Computer*"

Restart your browser and the ActiveX scripts will not be shown.

Comment: -1. I believe that the user asked how to uninstall an ocx rather then enable/disable ocx run through security settings